# Any Help would thanks : Product of continuous and Riemann integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let f:[a,b]→R be continuous. Suppose that for every Riemann integrable function g:[a,b]→R the product fg is Riemann integrable and integral a to b fg=0

Prove that f(x)=0 for all x in [a,b]

I know intutively and roughly but It's complicated for me to write in mathmatical symbol.

Comment: Is it possible to taking g(x)=f(x) for proving?
If so proving is much easier.

Comment: Yes @user....but remember that first you have to prove $\;f\;$ is Riemann integrable (it is almost trivial).

Answer (score 0):

A continuous function is automatically Riemann integrable, and the product of two Riemann integrable functions is Riemann integrable.

Assume that $f(x_0)=:p>0$ for some $x_0\in[a,b]$. There is an $h>0$ and an interval $I\subset[a,b]$ of length $h$ containing $x_0$ such that $f(x)\geq{p\over2}$ for all $x\in I$. Put $g(x):=1$ for $x\in I$ and $:=0$ otherwise. Then
$$\int_a^b f(x)\>g(x)\ dx\geq{p\over2}\>h>0\ ,$$
contrary to assumption.